# compile large project within emacs

Tags: emacs, compilation

A large project may have directory with several level depth. Emacs's default compile command is `"make -k"`, if I modified a certain source code, then typed `"M-x compile RET RET"`, it will execute `"make -k"` under the directory which the source code lies.

I think I can write a function to determine if the Makefile exist under current directory, if yes, keep searching under the parent directory until find the top level directory, then execute the building command, it would be right like my expectation.

However, I'm not very clearly how to start, could anyone give me some hints to start? Like the function or variable I may encounter. Thanks.

Comment: While this is not an answer to your question, in such cases I usually run `M-x compile` in the top directory once, leave the compilation buffer open, and just run `M-x recompile` after at.  The compilation buffer stays in the directory first used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use something like:

```
(setq compile-command
      '(let ((mf (locate-dominating-file default-directory "Makefile")))
         (if mf (setq mf (file-name-directory mf)))
         (concat (if (and mf (not (equal mf default-directory)))
                     (format "cd %s; "
                             (shell-quote-argument
                              (file-relative-name
                               (directory-file-name mf)))))
                 "make -k ")))
```

Comment: It seems your compile-command will check the parent directory, however, the depth might be over two, it won't work if so.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [smarter-compile](http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/smarter-compile) in marmalade.

From the documentation....When you require it, you can specify a list of cons cells, each one like `(TEST . COMMAND)`.

COMMAND is used for the `compile-command` when
the TEST succeeds.

TEST can be:

- a string. In this case it is used as a regex,
  and matched against the filename associated to the
  buffer. The TEST succeeds when the regex matches.
- a symbol, representing the major-mode. In this case
  if the buffer uses that major mode, the TEST
  succeeds.
- a symbol, representing any function with a name not
  ending in \"-mode\". In this case, the function is
  called and if it returns non-nil, the TEST
  succeeds.
- a list of forms.  In this case the forms are eval'd,
  and if the return value is non-nil, the TEST
  succeeds.

So you could produce a function that does the scan for makefile in parent directories, 
and use that as your TEST.

According to the documentation, if the COMMAND is nil, then the package uses the result of the TEST as the compile command. Which means you would need only one function, returning a make command referencing the makefile in the appropriate directory.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at: http://emacswiki.org/emacs/CompileCommand

"C-h v compile-command" directly from emacs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for people who prefer bash scripting over Emacs Lisp. In my .emacs I define a command which saves all buffers and runs a bash script which compiles the project.

```
(defun save-all-and-compile () (interactive)
 (save-some-buffers 1)
 (shell-command "make-and-run.sh &"))
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook (lambda ()
 (local-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'save-all-and-compile)))
```

For small projects the script could be as simple as

```
#!/bin/bash
make -j && ./<main>
```

where 'main' is the name of your executable. For larger projects one would first need to locate the root directory. Similarly, you could have different scripts (bound for different keys) for building and running the program. And then some more scripts for testing different parts of the project. But these are just details one can figure out for themselves.

Make sure the script is run asynchronously using '&'. This way the *Async Shell Command* buffer will open with the output from make and your project and will stay open.

**EDIT**

Based on the discussion below it appears I have initially overthought it and the solution is quite simple. Instead of passing the usual 'make' or 'make -k' to compile-command one could use a shell script which first navigates to the project's root directory and the builds.

```
(setq compile-command "script.sh")
```

Comment: What if the compilation stage has errors? Might be better to set compile-command to your shell script, but still use compile, rather than shell-command, to build it. Then you can define regexps for the errors -- if the defaults are not suitable for your situation -- such that pressing RET on an error in the *compilation* buffer will jump to the offending code. That is the primary benefit of compiling within emacs.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have limited experience with Emacs and am still working on turning it into an ideal IDE.

Comment: Ok I just realized what you really meant. The idea was to simply replace 'shell-command' with 'compile' in the initial solution and lose the '&'. This is indeed much better.

Comment: Not quite what I had in mind. First of all, I assume you are using (save-some-buffers 1) to replace the prompting behavior of M-x compile. Best to let compile do it for you and, if the prompt bothers you, customize the compilation-ask-about-save variable. Now, if you also customize compile-command to "make-and-run.csh" then you won't need emacs-make-and-run anymore; you can just use compile instead. Also note, the way you are using (cd topdir) might have subtle side-effects which you may or may not want.

Comment: Again, thanks for correcting me. The side-effects of (cd topdir) already started annoying me so that was a poor idea. In the end it appears the solution is quite simple. I didn't know compile-command was able to handle anything other than 'make <options>'. As I said, I'm still learning Emacs.